# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 6: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django, teradata

I tried a number of solutions on line, but still got the same error at my browser http://127.0.0.1:7000/json/json_data_dump. Can anyone please help?
By the way, if I do below and only insert the non-French character in Teradata, my code will work.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
    Category    varchar(80) not null,         -- CHARACTER SET UNICODE,
```

Below is the python code:

```
def json_data_dump(request):
    sql = """ select category as dept from db.tablename order by 1;"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, teradata_con())

    df_dept = df[['dept']].drop_duplicates()    

    dic = {'dept':[]}
    for index, row in df_dept.iterrows():        
        dic['dept'].append({                   
                'dept':row['dept'].decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")   #.encode("utf-8")    #.decode('latin-1')       #decode("utf-8")                                 
            })                

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dic,encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))  
    # return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dic,ensure_ascii=False) )
```

Comment: That error indicates the data *is not UTF8*. Which seems to be correct; `0xe9` is the Latin-1 code for the "French" character `é`.

Comment: sorry, it's not the French character causing error. It’s some dash (they look like dash, but they are not) in the table causing trouble. I replaced it with the normal dash then it’s working. case solved.